# msys2 error in installing requirements.txt for ESP-IDF

Tags: linux, unix, msys2, msys, esp-idf

I am trying to install the requirements.txt using "pip install -r requirements.txt" for ESP-IDF in msys32 but getting this error.

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
failed to create process (C:\msys32\mingw32\bin\python2.exe "D:\dozee\dozee_compiler\msys32\mingw32\bin\pip-script.py" "install" "-r" "requirements.txt").
```

Comment: Hi! In general, it helps to post your IDF version and other specifics of your environment. If you won't get an answer here, you may want to ask in the esp32 forum.

Comment: It is giving error in all IDF version. Currently I am using IDFv- 3.3 and v4.2-dev-1905-g625bd5eb1

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have encountered this problem before with the ESP8266 RTOS SDK. I solved it by adding the 'python2.exe' or whichever python you are using to the PATH variables.